# Buffering actions in with redux-observable

Tags: rxjs, buffer, redux-observable

I consume WebSocket service which produce a lot of events and I would like to buffer some actions that are triggered by WS events, depending on the time specified in the store (buffering can be disabled so it can also be 0 ms). As for now I have something similar to:

```
const eventEpic = (action$, store) => {
    return action$.ofType(ACTION)
        ::bufferWhen((action) => {
            const { time } = action.payload;

            return time > 0
                ? Observable.interval(time)
                : action$.ofType(ACTION);
        })
        ::map((bufferedActions) => writeToStoreAction(...));
};
```

This solution works, however I have a feeling that it can be implemented better.

`bufferWhen` is provided with function which returns stream that indicates when buffer should be closed - if time specified it returns interval, if not, it closes the stream as soon as it receives `ACTION`.

Is this approach correct? ;-)

Regards,
Mateusz

Comment: Hey, you mention "depending on the time specified in the store" but in your example it's coming from the action, not the store. `action.payload.time`

Comment: Well yes, that's because I wanted to avoid accessing the store so many times.

Initially I was accessing the store, in every `bufferWhen`, then I created another epic which cached `time` value once `time` was changed, but this wasn't pure, so my college came up with such idea.

Comment: Cool, are you saying your question is outdated and that you don't really want to get the time from the store?

Comment: What I just realised is that in `bufferWhen` I should probably return observable merged with `action$.ofType(SET_TIME_ACTION)` to make sure that current buffer will close immediately.

Comment: I'd like to get the time from the store, because user should be able to pick buffering time (e.g. 5 seconds, 10 seconds etc.). So the question is actually up to date :)

Comment: Why buffer actions triggered by the events and not the events themselves?

Comment: The `bufferWhen` function can just be `action => Observable.interval(action.payload.time)`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this

> buffer some actions  ... depending on the time specified in the store ... wanted to avoid accessing the store so many times

```js
const time$ = Observable.of(this.store.getBufferTime());

const eventEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return time$.switchMap(time => {
     action$.ofType(ACTION)
       ::bufferWhen(() => Observable.interval(time) )
       ::map((bufferedActions) => writeToStoreAction(...));
   }
};
```

I'm not familiar with epics, so you may have to tweak this.

**Edit**

Actually, since the `bufferWhen` no longer has conditional logic,

```
     action$.ofType(ACTION)
       ::buffer(Observable.interval(time))
```

**Edit #2**

A couple of problems occur in the above code

1) **Empty buffers emits**
`buffer` returns an array of values, but at times the array can be empty, since `Observable.interval(time)` which triggers a buffer flush can emit ***faster*** than the rate of events being buffered. This is apparent when 'time === 0', but can also occur when 'time > 0'.
The simple fix is to filter out empty buffers.

2) **Lost events**
`switchMap` can cause lost events when `time` changes and a new inner observable replaces the old inner observable. Any events in the old inner observable buffer are not emitted, therefore lost.
The fix for this is to add a flush event to the buffer trigger. The `do` operator sends the flush event into the inner observable ***before*** the switchMap runs. Trying to use `time$` in place of `flush$` doesn't work.

```js
const time$ = Observable.of(this.store.getBufferTime());
const flush$ = new Rx.Subject()

const eventEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return time$
    .do(x => flush$.next(true))
    .switchMap(time => 
      action$.ofType(ACTION)
        ::buffer(Observable.interval(time).merge(flush$))
        ::filter(events => events.length > 0)
        ::map((bufferedActions) => writeToStoreAction(...));
};
```

Comment: Not really actually, because when time in store will equal 0, then we will create `Observable.interval(0)` which would close buffer immediately after it was opened.

Comment: Observable.interval(0) fires continuously, which stops the buffer buffering anything, which is what you wanted for  time === 0.

Comment: Sorry, I ran a test - you're sort of correct - I'm getting a bunch of empty buffers so a filter seems in order. The good news is, all of the event stream is being emitted. I'll tidy up and post  the test environment.

Comment: There's another problem related to `switchMap`. When `time` is changed, the contents of the buffer since the last emit are lost, because the change causes a new observable to be created, discarding the old one and throwing away the buffer contents. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that it took so long to reply, but actually my buffering solution evaluated over time and had to handle more cases.

Please find my final solution below. Hope it will help someone ;)

```js
const eventEpic = (action$, store) => {
  // Take stream of actions which have to be buffered
  return action$.ofType(ACTION)
    ::map((action) => action.payload)
    // Get stream of those actions, but only actions which are in specific time frame.
    // I use it to ignore actions which are received when I don't need them
    ::windowToggle(
      action$.ofType(BUFFER_WINDOW_OPENING_ACTION), // in my example it is some success async operation
      () => action$.ofType(BUFFER_WINDOW_CLOSING_ACTION), // in my example it is initiation of some async operation
    )
    // Get new stream of changes
    ::switchMap((changes$) => {
      return changes$
        // Close buffer on
        // - each 1000 ms (or _bufferTime, depending which is higher), or
        // - disptach of user actions which should immidiatelly close the buffer to update the view
        ::bufferWhen(() => {
          return merge(
            interval(Math.max(1000, _bufferTime)),
            action$.ofType(
              SOME_SPECIFIC_USER_ACTION_1,
              SOME_OTHER_USER_ACTION_2,
            ),
          );
        })
        ::filter((buffer) => buffer.length > 0)
        // Take actions as long as BUFFER_WINDOW_CLOSING_ACTION is not dispatched
        ::takeUntil(action$.ofType(BUFFER_WINDOW_CLOSING_ACTION))
        ::map((result) => writeToStoreAction(result));
    });
};
```